# Run script from standard out, and pass arguments

Tags: bash

I've seen a trick a number of times where the content of a script is downloaded from a web-server, and then executed. This script may also accept command-line arguments.

I can't seem to find such a script to use as an example when I need it, though.

Can anyone provide an example of this?

Answer (score 2):

The `-s` flag does what you are talking about here.

```
$ echo 'echo "Arguments: $@"' | bash -s foo bar baz
Arguments: foo bar baz
$ echo 'echo "Arguments: $@"' | bash -s
Arguments:
$ echo 'echo "Arguments: $@"' | bash -s flkejflk
Arguments: flkejflk
```

It should probably be mentioned that the general pattern of the `curl | bash` idiom uses `http` which makes it **hideously** unsafe. Using `https` only makes this *slightly* better since you have no way of knowing that the code you got a minute ago is the code you'll get a minute from now (among other things).

Comment: That sounds right. Is there any way to route to the correct script parser/engine, so that this will work agnosticly for any type of script (Bash, Python, Perl, etc..)?

Comment: Route what to who? You mean put something on the right-hand side of that pipe which detects the incoming streams language and punts to the correct interpreter? It should be possible via shebang/etc. sniffing but I don't know of anything that does that offhand. And it would be susceptible to incorrect guessing causing problems/failures.

Comment: I just figured that, since the shell already knows how to parse the shebang and pump the script into the correct parser in some capacity, that there was some way to have the shell process it here, too. It doesn't seem reasonable that we can't do the equivalent of "./script" from STDIN.

Comment: The kernel handles shebang lines actually. The shell might as a fallback but I don't think it has to. And it doesn't do that for stdin because "Why would you pipe to the shell if you weren't giving it shell script code?" or something, I don't know. But yes, shebang sniffing would certainly be possible.

Comment: That's interesting. Are you familiar with what kernel interface is used to do this (this seems way out-of-scope for the kernel to manage)?

Comment: More than you likely ever wanted to know about shebang: http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/